# R calculating yearly or normalized growth rates for different interval lengths

Tags: r, dataframe, dplyr

I have a data frame of the structure shown below. I want to calculate yearly growth rates. Problem is that not for all models the length of time steps is the same. In the example below, REMIND delivers data in 5 year intervals, while TIAM-ECN has 10 year intervals.

```
model     scenario  region  year  value
REMIND    Base  NORTH_AM    2010  314.1330
REMIND    Base    CHINA+    2010  1325.9220
REMIND    RefPol  NORTH_AM  2010  314.1330
REMIND    RefPol  CHINA+    2010  1325.9220
TIAM-ECN  Base    NORTH_AM  2010  344.4005
TIAM-ECN  Base    CHINA+    2010  1341.3352
TIAM-ECN  RefPol  NORTH_AM  2010  344.4005
TIAM-ECN  RefPol  CHINA+    2010  1341.3352
REMIND    Base    NORTH_AM  2015  327.6270
REMIND    Base    CHINA+    2015  1354.3180
REMIND    RefPol  NORTH_AM  2015  327.6270
REMIND    RefPol  CHINA+    2015  1354.3180
REMIND    Base    NORTH_AM  2020  340.8490
REMIND    Base    CHINA+    2020  1372.4630
REMIND    RefPol  NORTH_AM  2020  340.8490
REMIND    RefPol  CHINA+    2020  1372.4630
TIAM-ECN  Base    NORTH_AM  2020  374.2647
TIAM-ECN  Base    CHINA+    2020  1387.7915
TIAM-ECN  RefPol  NORTH_AM  2020  374.2647
TIAM-ECN  RefPol  CHINA+    2020  1387.7915
```

Computing growth rates for the different intervals is simple:

```
library(dplyr)

tmp_gr <- group_by(df, model, scenario, region) %>%
  mutate(value = value / lag(value) - 1) %>%
  ungroup()
```

yields (where I left out the NAs for 2010):

```
model     scenario region   year    value
REMIND    Base     NORTH_AM 2015    -0.7557456
REMIND    Base     CHINA+   2015    3.1337191
REMIND    RefPol   NORTH_AM 2015    -0.7580871
REMIND    RefPol   CHINA+   2015    3.1337191
REMIND    Base     NORTH_AM 2020    -0.7483242
REMIND    Base     CHINA+   2020    3.0266012
REMIND    RefPol   NORTH_AM 2020    -0.7516516
REMIND    RefPol   CHINA+   2020    3.0266012
TIAM-ECN  Base     NORTH_AM 2020    -0.7273044
TIAM-ECN  Base     CHINA+   2020    2.7080483
TIAM-ECN  RefPol   NORTH_AM 2020    -0.7303164
TIAM-ECN  RefPol   CHINA+   2020    2.7080483
```

But now, computing yearly growth rates by dividing the interval growth rate with the interval lenght

```
tmp_gr_yearly <- group_by(df, model, scenario, region) %>%
  mutate(value = (value / lag(value) - 1) / (year - lag(year))) %>%
  ungroup()
```

yields:

```
model     scenario region   year   value
REMIND    Base     NORTH_AM 2015    -0.1511491
REMIND    Base     CHINA+   2015    Inf
REMIND    RefPol   NORTH_AM 2015    -Inf
REMIND    RefPol   CHINA+   2015    Inf
REMIND    Base     NORTH_AM 2020    -0.1496648
REMIND    Base     CHINA+   2020    Inf
REMIND    RefPol   NORTH_AM 2020    -Inf
REMIND    RefPol   CHINA+   2020    Inf
TIAM-ECN  Base     NORTH_AM 2020    -Inf
TIAM-ECN  Base     CHINA+   2020    Inf
TIAM-ECN  RefPol   NORTH_AM 2020    -Inf
TIAM-ECN  RefPol   CHINA+   2020    Inf
```

I do not understand where the `Inf` come from.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My example of calculating the simple, non-normalized growth rates was wrong already.

Anyway, I think I figured it out myself:

```
tmp_gr <- group_by(df, model, scenario, region) %>%
  mutate(value = lag(value, n=0, order_by=year) / lag(value, order_by=year) - 1) %>%
  ungroup()

 tmp_gr_yearly <- group_by(df, model, scenario, region) %>%
   mutate(value = (lag(value, n=0, order_by=year) / lag(value, order_by=year) - 1) / (lag(year, n=0, order_by=year) - lag(year, order_by=year))) %>%
 ungroup()
```

By using the lag-operator for all values and explicitly telling the order, the whole things gets robust against non-ordered data.